Android resource linking failed ERROR:AAPT: aapt2.exe
Android resource linking failed
ERROR:AAPT: aapt2.exe E 12-04 17:13:23 12032 11752 LoadedArsc.cpp:94] RES_TABLE_TYPE_TYPE entry offsets overlap actual entry data.
aapt2.exe E 12-04 17:13:23 12032 11752 ApkAssets.cpp:149] Failed to load resources table in APK 'C:\Users\yopi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-35\android.jar'.
error: failed to load include path C:\Users\yopi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-35\android.jar.
i try reinstall the sdk after removing it
